# Copy all data between linux partitions

Tags: data-recovery, arch-linux

I used to have a Windows 10/Arch Linux dual boot. As I don't need Windows anymore, I deleted it and wanted to expand Arch.

I created a new Arch partition, made it bootable.

Now, what should I copy to get all my data on this new partition ? Obviously /home isn't enough, I have lots of stuff everywhere on the filesystem, and the whole of it on a single /partition.

I first thought of using `cp -ru --p=links`, but I'm not sure.

EDIT:
I finally installed GParted Live, and used it, it worked perfectly.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you sure you are after a file level (rather then block level) solution?

Comment: In fine I'd like to have a large Arch Linux partition on my whole drive -exept BIOS, EFI, and Swap. However Windows was left of Linux and I don't have a live GParted. So I'm trying to clone the old partition into the first one.

Comment: To clone  partition you copy the partition, not the files.  You may also have some irritation moving the boot loader.  You have not provided sufficient information about your disk to enable meaningful answers.  You may want to provide the outputs of (run as root) "lsblk; lvs" to give us a feel for your setup.   That said, have you looked at gparted?   This program can do lots of magic with moving partitions arround and resizing them - but, of-course, BACK UP FIRST.

Comment: I don't know how I managed to mess my partition up like that : the old partition doesn't boot anymore, grub-mkconfig fails, and so on... if I manage to start it again, i'll install gparted.

Comment: Have you tried using Supergrub 2 to rescue/boot your system? - https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/ as got me out of a pickle more then once

Comment: Ok I managed to get my old archlinux working again. I burnt GParted on a USB stick and I'm stuck on the Debian login / warranty page.

Comment: Lots of distrubitions have gparted on their live ISO, MX-Linux, Mint, Ubuntus... which one has the weird login/warranty page? Or just use a different one

Comment: I tried using the standalone GParted live. It appeared that my bios starts in UEFI mode, then falls back into Legacy mode on failure. And GParted Live doesn't refuse the UEFI mode. I have to swap to Legacy, use GParted, then switch back to UEFI mode.